# Differences between RHC and control horizon in MPC

Tags: optimization

I have used model predictive control strategy in order to optimize a linear discrete SISo model.

For example:

$x(t+1)=-2x(t)+4u(t)$

Where I want to regulate my state $x(t)$ at the desired point (a simple regulating problem).

In every step, I predict $20$ future samples such that MPC optimizes next $20$ time instances (prediction horizon$=20$) and obtains $20$ responses for control variable(control horizon $=20$) then based on RHC technique, I just apply $10$ samples to model.
I know both control horizon and prediction horizon are $20$ samples. but what about applied samples ($10$ samples) what can I name my applied samples?

Comment: It's not called anything particular, and I would not try to invent some special name to this. It's just MPC but with the small change that you don't update already after one sample as often as one normally does.

Comment: Just a remark: Using acronyms without writing them out at the first usage is a very bad communication style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another term clearly to name control sequences in this case: **manipulated control sequence** means some consecutive sequences of decision variables which are ready to be applied to the system.

Comment: control time steps = control sampling time $T_s$, manipulated variable = control variable $\boldsymbol{u}(t)$, more formulation at [here](http://dro.deakin.edu.au/eserv/DU:30112367/mohammadi-enhancinghuman-2018.pdf#page=65).

Answer (score 0):

based on an article (Fig.2):

https://doi.org/10.3390/en11030631

**control time steps** is a word to define the time between control updates and iterative receding horizon optimization.